# HDIV and Spring MVC - After startPage

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, hdiv

In HDIV, after I've configured my startpage, where should I define the other address that are allowed after it?

PS: I have already configured the user flow in spring.

I'm using the last Spring MVC.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you claim "I define the other address that are allowed after it", what do you mean?